# Multiple file input - split string on certain space

Tags: regex, bash, shell, kdialog

I'm using kdialog's file selection dialog to help me select multiple files and store the location of said files into an array. Unfortunately the string that is captured by kdialog has a whitespace as a delimiter. So kdialog essentially retrieves a string that looks like this:

```
/home/file 1.jpg /home/file 2.jpg /home/file 3.jpg
```

I'm essentially trying to split this string so it would look like this:

```
/home/file 1.jpg 
/home/file 2.jpg 
/home/file 3.jpg
```

I tried using this code to split it

```
IFS=' /' read -r -a array <<< "$variable"
```

But it wasn't working. Prior to using kdialog, I was using zenity's file selection dialog, which has an output like this:

```
/home/file 1.jpg|/home/file 2.jpg|/home/file 3.jpg
```

That output was easier to split with this code;

```
IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< "$variable"
```

But kdialog's thumbnails can be resized while zenity's can't, hence why I'm trying to use kdialog.

Comment: will you really only be using this for `.jpg` files? (I would guess not, but who knows?). You need to show the code that generating the file list. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
vars=$(kdialog "${PWD}" --getopenfilename --multiple --separate-output)
```

Is preferable.

Not only it's a "native" functionality, but, while separating the files into lines by editing the output text with sed can work, the obvious downside is that it's limited to filenames without spaces. Filenames containing spaces will be split.

$PWD is generally preferable to "." While kdialog itself replaces it correctly, sometimes you may end up with the literal relative "." rather than the more likely wanted full path.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable=$(kdialog --getopenfilename --multiple .);
variable=$(echo $variable | sed 's/\ \//\\n\//g')
kdialog --msgbox "$variable";
```